# Elinks and flash

Tags: linux, shell, flash, elinks

is there a possibility to "use" flash based objects with elinks ?

I mean, i have an online flash based multiplayer game ( http://haxball.appspot.com ) and i want to connect to game with elinks installed on my shell server to create an always-present game room.

To do it, i need a terminal-based webbrowser with flash support. There is an elinks installed so it would be great if there is such a possibility in it.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Flash needs an X server/client to work with which obviously can't be possible with a terminal.

Comment: yeah i realize that but maybe there's any smart tool to converting flash animations into raw text ? I know that it can be extremely hard to create or even imposible but we have some geniuses on our planet hehe

Comment: That is possible for video files but not flash animations as far as I know :-)

Answer (score 0):

> To do it, i need a terminal-based webbrowser with flash support

There's always more than one way to do stuff. Install Tightvnc server, run it with .xinitrc containting

```
firefox &
exec xterm
```

done!